# Best router/s for timely updates and decent security?

Tags: router

I’ve had a few routers and they all have suffered from poor update support, often getting abandoned in the update department after only 6 months. As I am constantly reading about insecure routers, how can I pick a good one that will receive updates and be reasonable from a security standpoint? I’m reluctant to flash a device with os firmware, I’d prefer something that doesn’t take a masters in networking to figure out.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

It is not so much about the router as it is about the firmware which is running on that hardware. You can buy any device which is supported by DD-WRT - just check the [list](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices).

DD-WRT also pushed a fix for the latest vulnerability known as [KRACK](https://www.krackattacks.com/#details).

http://svn.dd-wrt.com/changeset/33525

The thing is that you should go with better maintained firmware.